# C++: Reading CSV file into struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, csv, struct

I am working on an assignment where I need to read a CSV file of unknown number of lines into an structured array. Only via C++, not C (they don't want us to combine both).

So, I have following code:

```
// DEFINITION
struct items {
    int ID;
    string name;
    string desc;
    string price;
    string pcs;
};

void step1() {

    string namefile, line;
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Name of the file:" << endl;
    cin >> namefile;

    ifstream file;

    file.open(namefile);

    if( !file.is_open()) {

        cout << "File "<< namefile <<" not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);

    }

    while ( getline( file, line) ) { // To get the number of lines in the file
        counter++;
    }

    items* item = new items[counter]; // Add number to structured array

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        file >> item[i].ID >> item[i].name >> item[i].desc >> item[i].price >> item[i].pcs;

    }

    cout << item[1].name << endl;

    file.close();
}
```

But when I run the code, the app will return space after reading and I actually think it's not reading at all. Here is the output in the console:

```
Name of the file:
open.csv

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first loop reads the stream. It stops when there is nothing else left to read. At that point the stream goes into failure mode (i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` gets set) and it will refuse to read anything until it gets somehow restored.

You can restore a file to goid state using `file. clear()`. That alone won't help, though, as the stream is still at its end. You could seek to the start before reading but I wouldn't do that. Instead, I would read the file in one pass and `push_back()` each element to a `std::vector<items>`.

Note that the input you have for each `items` record probably doesn't quite do what you want it to do: if you really have a CSV file you'll need to read to the separators (e.g. the `,`) and ignore the separator after reading the ID. Also, you should always test the state of the stream after reading. Your loop could e.g. look something like this:

```
for (items i;
      (file >> i.id).ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',')
      && std::getline(file, i.name, ',')
      && std::getline(file, i.desc, ',')
      && std::getline(file, i.price, ',')
      && std::getline(file, i.pcs); ) {
    is.push_back(i);
}
```

What is needed exactly somewhat depends on the exact file format.

Comment: I didn't know that it stays at the end after loop so thanks for the explanation and hank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your file pointer is at the end of the file after the while loop to determine the amount of lines. As I see it you've got the clear and reset the file pointer. This link might help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11564/