# Populate dynamics array from file

Tags: c++

What is the best way to populate array "in fly" when reading file lines?

[I found similar solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302836/c-reading-csv-file-into-struct-array)

But firstly the programmer looping through the file to get numbers of lanes and then in another loop saving content to structure.

I'm looking for the way how to do it in one loop

Comment: The accepted to that question answer does just that: `push_back` into an `std::vector`

Comment: Are you thinking of a dynamic array that is not an `std::vector`?

Comment: Doesn't matter if is std::vector std:array etc.
I'm looking for efficient way :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `malloc` / `realloc` to read the array with unknown structure on the fly.
Use custom unidirectional lists or `std::list` when it is not memory and access-time critical.